# <cfinput> string inside a javascript block causing issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion

I have the following jQuery (admittedly messy at the moment) which appends a new row to a table. However, it's not inserting the `<cfinput>` field. In fact, somehow coldfusion is reading that  tag inside the javascript block because it throws a CF error.

```
Context validation error for tag cfinput.The tag must be nested inside a cfform tag
```

If I change it to a normal `<input>`, then the problems go away and the field is inserted.

I need the `<cfinput>` to make use of ColdFusion's native date picker. Regardless, I'm curious why this is happening.

```
    $(".aAddLine").click(function(e){   
                var clickedID = $(this).attr("id");
                var lineNo = parseInt(clickedID.split("_")[1])
                var newLineNo = parseInt(lineNo+1)
                var x = "";
                $('#tdPlus_' + lineNo).html("");
                x += '<tr>';
                x += '<td width="50" class="tdPlus' + newLineNo + '"><a class="aAddLine" id="aAddLine_' + newLineNo + '" href="##">+ Line</a></td>';
                x += '<td valign="top">Date</td>';
/*issue with the <cfinput> on the line below */
                x += '<td><cfinput class="dt validate" type="datefield" name="startDate" id="startDate_' + newLineNo + '" validate="eurodate" mask="dd/mm/yyyy" />&nbsp;<span class="res" id="resStartDate_' + newLineNo + '"> <span class="hint"></span></span></td>';
                x += '<td style="width:10px">&nbsp;</td>';
                x += '<td>Time</td>'
                x += '<td><input class="validate" type="datefield" name="startTime_' + newLineNo + '" id="startTime_' + newLineNo + '" style="width:35px;"/>&nbsp;<span class="res" id="resStartTime_' + newLineNo + '"></span>&nbsp;to&nbsp;<input class="validate" type="datefield" name="endTime_' + newLineNo + '" id="endTime_' + newLineNo + '" style="width:35px;"/>&nbsp;<span class="res" id="resEndTime_' + newLineNo + '""></span></td>'
                x += '</tr>'
                $('#tblItem > tbody:last').append(x);
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
            });
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot add CF form tags via JavaScript.  JavaScript happens in the browser LONG after ColdFusion has done any processing it needs to do. By that time anything that *was* a CFINPUT tag (or any ColdFusion tag) has now been converted to HTML.

If you need to dynamically add fields to a form, just add regular old HTML form elements. Look at the source code in the browser and you will see that is what is being delivered to the browser.  Neither JS or the browser have any idea what ColdFusion or CFINPUT are.

Comment: I'm really curious why someone downvoted this answer.  Am I inaccurate in anyway? Please leave a comment.

Comment: The user wanted to know why his code was erroring, you didn't touch on that.  Yes you explained what he was doing was wrong but his main question or concern IMO was "Regardless, I'm curious why this is happening." and you answer didn't help, so to me that's a down vote.

Comment: So explaining that what the user was trying to do was completely wrong in the first place isn't helpful?  You're right, I did not explain why it was throwing an error. But the rest of my answer is still helpful. Instead of a downvote you could edit my answer with the additional information. That improves the quality of the answer (which is the point of a wiki answer).  Unless you're just more interested in upping your own reputation by trying to get your answer selected instead of mine, then you're on the right track.

Comment: I currently don’t have privilege to edit answers or questions, so I don’t do so.  Even if I did (have privilege) I wouldn’t edit someone's answer if I felt they completely missed the original question because some of his information was helpful.  Also at the time that I posted my answer both you and Pretish had posted seemingly similar answers and IMO neither of you addressed the original question.  So who’s answer should I have edited, both?  No, I wrote my own and voted down because you missed the question.  In retrospect I shouldn’t have voted down your answer.

Comment: If you don't feel like editing (which is fair enough), you can/should leave a comment on the answer with the most upvotes to say what you think needs changing, and on any related ones just say "see what I said to X".

If you're going to add a new answer (also fair enough), it's a good idea to encompass points covered by existing answers (and if necessary state why they are incomplete/lacking).

Avoid downvoting competing answers unless they are actively wrong/harmful (rather than just incomplete or missing the point).

Answer (score 2):

I’m assuming the page that contains the JS is a ColdFusion page, so it tries to parse anything with "<CF".  Looking at your code, cfinput *is* a valid ColdFusion tag and it’s *not* within a cfform making the code invalid, so when CF tries to render your page for the first time it errors.

Like the others have stated, having a cfinput at that level won't work and you should just use a jQuery plugin or get the contents of the <cfinput> via aJax or some other way.

Answer (score 0):

CFINPUT is coldfusion tag and process at the time of ColdFusion page is compiling and when you are try to add it through jQuery (Using javascript) it doesn't process by ColdFusion as you are working at Browser level and Server do not have any idea about this. And in this case CFINPUT is not a valid HTML tag.